# I want to give chess tutorials, which software should I use?

Tags: software

I think that I am a enough good chess player to teach chess. So, I want to create a website and post chess videos in it. So I want a software that helps me teach chess like for example see this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VDfjsMXlcek
This video was given by thechesswebsite.com. Note the software that he uses, I asked him about it but he is not replying so I want your help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: how to get yellow arrow for each and every move played ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just based on ease of use and aesthetic appeal I'd recommend the free [ChessBase Reader](https://en.chessbase.com/pages/download) which allows you to easily draw arrows on the board and highlight squares. To record your videos you can use free screen capture software such as [oCam](http://ohsoft.net/product_ocam.php).

Comment: It's a pleasure. Please post a link to your videos when you're ready to release them! :)

Comment: Ok, but it will take time.

Comment: How, to draw arrows and highlight squares?

Comment: To draw a green arrow hold down Alt and drag the mouse from the source to the target square. For red arrows hold down Alt+Shift, for yellow Alt+Shift+Ctrl. The same goes for highlighting squares.

Comment: Checkout my first tutorial: http://chessworld.tk/videos/strategy/chess-strategy-forks.html